# why is my sequelize query that sums a decimal column returning as a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am summing a decimal column and it is being returned as a string instead of an integer?

```
exports.sumMoney = function (id) {
    return myModel.findAll({
        raw: true,
        attributes: [[sequelize.fn('SUM', sequelize.col('moneycol')), 'moneylabel']],
        where: { id: id }
    }).then(r => r);
}
```

Comment: Please post the output of `sumMoney`.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if you're using MySQL or Postgres, but adding this to the configuration fixed my issue on MySQL

```
dialectOptions: {
    decimalNumbers: true
}
```

Comment: Great, that solve my problem with mysql but when I switch to MariaDB it's not working, any idea why ?

Comment: Doesn't work on Postgres with Sequelize v6.

Answer (score 6):

In order to convert result to number you need to perform explicit cast using sequelize.cast function:

```
exports.sumMoney = function (id) {
    return myModel.findAll({
        raw: true,
        attributes: [[sequelize.cast(sequelize.fn('SUM', sequelize.col('moneycol')), 'int'), 'moneylabel']],
        where: { id: id }
    }).then(r => r);
}
```

I don't know why it isn't stated in sequelize v4 docs, but v3 states that:

> An explicit cast is required on postgres.

http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/api/sequelize/#fnfn-args-sequelizefn

Answer (score 2):

Some days ago i did fix that problem.
Only you need to use `SIGNED` instead of `int`.

```
[Transacciones.sequelize.cast(Transacciones.sequelize.fn('SUM', Transacciones.sequelize.col('fare')), 'SIGNED'), 'fare'],
```

Answer (score 1):

I found two ways to solve it

1. By Passing **get()** method in Model

   ```
   discountPercentage: {
    type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(18, 3),
    allowNull: true,
    defaultValue: 0.000,
    get() {
      return parseFloat(this.getDataValue('discountPercentage')) || null;
    }
   },
   ```
2. Same as ow3n's answer by setting **dialectOptions** (I have tried with MySQL)

   ```
   new Sequelize('mysql://root@localhost:3306/database',{ 
     dialectOptions: 
      { 
        decimalNumbers: true 
      }
   })
   ```